# Need to see if the last file is the same as the previous file

Tags: python

I'm using [`yolov5`](https://pytorch.org/hub/ultralytics_yolov5/) to detect people and I'm using the following code to read the files containing the number of people and display it:

```
import os

directory_path = r'C:\Users\MRTS\yolov5\runs\detect\exp2\labels'

os.chdir(directory_path)

most_recent_file = None
most_recent_time = 0

while True:
    for entry in os.scandir(directory_path):
        if entry.is_file():
            # get the modification time of the file using entry.stat().st_mtime_ns
            mod_time = entry.stat().st_mtime_ns
            if mod_time > most_recent_time:
                # update the most recent file and its modification time
                most_recent_file = r'{}'.format(entry.name)
                most_recent_time = mod_time
                
    # open the file for reading 
    with open(most_recent_file, 'r') as f:  
    # read file contents into a variable 
        lines = len(f.readlines())
        print('Total Number of People:', lines)
        time.sleep(3)
```

My problem is that if it doesn't detects people, it will not create a file, so this code would just keep reading the last one. I want to see if the most recent file is still the same as the previous and in that case, print that there are 0 people. Basically, if there are no new files, there are no people and I want to print that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable to keep track of the path of the `most_recent_file`, and only print if the new `most_recent_file` is different from it:

```
import os
import time

directory_path = "."
recently_parsed = None
while True:
    most_recent_time, most_recent_file = max(
        (
            (entry.stat().st_mtime_ns, entry.name)
            for entry in os.scandir(directory_path)
            if entry.is_file()
        )
    )
    with open(most_recent_file, "r") as f:
        if recently_parsed == most_recent_file:
            print("No new people")
        else:
            recently_parsed = most_recent_file
            lines = len(f.readlines())
            print("Total Number of People:", lines)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Note that I've also replaced the `most_recent_file` determination with a `max` call.

Comment: It works, but it prints "No new people" as many times as files are in the path, how can I make it print only one?

Comment: my continue was wrong, now it works fine :)